# Does ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault creates key in the the keyvault or I need to create it beforehand?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

The documentation does not specify if the key specified by key identifier will be created by the ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault method or if I have to manually create it in the keyvault. If I need to manually create the key what settings for that key should I use? If it creates the key automatically, when it does it and what exceptions does it throw because even when I provided wrong clientId and secretId it failed silently.

```
  services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("xxx"))
                .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(
                     keyIdentifier: "xxx",
                     clientId: "xxx",
                     clientSecret: "xxx");
```

Comment: thank you for asking this! Even though its not my first time with this setup I completely forgot about needing to create a key. As you said, its not specified in the docs and have spent the last few hours going over permissions which all seemed correct...because they were, was just missing the darn key :( :( :( :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to to create the key in advance in Azure Key Vault, because you are supposed to pass the full URL to **ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault**.

I typically create the key with these settings:

[image]

Also, when you link to the key, do ignore the version number, then you will point to the latest version of the key:

[image]